# Verizon FIOS battery warning beep

Tags: battery

My Verizon FIOS system has a back-up battery to keep the phone running in the event of a power failure. This battery is approaching the end of its life and makes a "BEEP" every five minutes or so. I tried unplugging the battery's wiring harness from the case, but that didn't work - the beeping continues.

Any ideas on how to make it stop?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a piece of consumer electronics, not any sort of home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the battery. Depending on who's responsibility maintaining the battery is, that's either you get a new battery or you call Verizon and have them replace it (which will be the easy way if it's their responsibility, and the expensive way if it's yours.)

If the system is looking for a good battery, neither a dying/dead one nor no battery at all is going to make it happy.

Comment: Before you replace it, try making sure all the connectors from it to the rest of the system are clean and secure. Occasionally connections don't get plugged in fully and eventually work loose.